# What are proven options for using ZFS remotely as a volume backend for docker?

Tags: docker, nfs, docker-volume, zfs

So with the introduction of volumes we do not longer use data-only containers! Nice. But right now I have this nice home-grown ZFS appliance and I want to use it as a backend for my docker volumes (of course Docker is running on other hosts).

I can export ZFS as NFS relatively easy, what are proven (i.e. battle-tested) options for using NFS as a volume backend for docker?

A google search shows me the following possibilities:

- using Flocker, I could use the flocker-agent-thingie on the zfs appliance. However with Flocker being scrapped, I am concerned...
- using the `local` volume backend and simply mount the nfs export on the docker host -> does not scale, but might do the job.
- using a specialized volume plugin like https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare to utilize nfs
- something alike from Rancher: https://github.com/rancher/convoy
- or going big and use Kubernetes and NFS as persistent storage https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs

I have pretty extensive single-host Docker knowledge - which option is a stable one? Performance is not that important to me (alas the use case is  a dockerized OwnCloud/NextCloud stack, throughput is limited by the internet connection)

Comment: If this is only for one Docker machine and one ZFS machine, the simplest option is probably the best. I'd go for manually mounting the filesystem and using the `local` backend.